# meta theme-color doesn't work on Chrome for Android 4.4.4

Tags: android, google-chrome, meta

I've using `<meta name="theme-color" content="#DB5945">` but I can't see any color theme changes on Chrome for Android version 4.4.4. My Chrome App is up to date.

Comment: Tag [tag:google-chrome-app] is not for Chrome itself.

Comment: Can you explain a little more? please @Xan

Comment: For the browser, use [tag:google-chrome]. The other tag is used for questions related to development on the Chrome Apps platform. Has nothing to do with your question, just the tags you used when submitting.

Comment: Ok I got it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be on Android version 5.0 Lollipop or higher to see the effects of your color theme. Having chrome updated to the latest version doesn't help as this is a feature that also depends on the Android version you are running.